# Microsoft Edge with IE mode

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Would anybody know if Edge with IE mode works on Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB build. I don't see it listed in the supported OS list here [About IE mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode)

Also - is the only way to configure this now via group policy? I see lots of articles making reference to an `#edge-internet-explorer-integration` flag but this flag isn't available in the latest version of Edge (83.0.478.64)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not believe you can do this (IE Mode) with the new Chromium Edge.  I have a machine here with both Edge Versions, and the legacy Edge still has IE mode.  If you really need IE from to time it should still be there yo run separately (which is what IE mode does anyway)

Comment: Thanks for you comment @John. I understand what you're saying about just using IE. Our issue is that we have a couple of legacy sites which still need IE (they use Silverlight). IE Mode in Edge caught my interest as we could just make Edge our default browser and then configure our legacy sites to open in IE Mode within Edge (eliminating the need of forcing users to open certain sites in IE and all other sites in Edge).

Comment: Edge 83.x is Microsoft Edge (Chromium) not Legacy Edge.  [The version of Edge you are using absolutely supports IE Mode.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies).  You would need to provide information on how you have configured the `Configure Internet Explorer integration.` policy.  As currently written your question cannot be answered due to the lack of the necessary information to answer you question.